# Tabulate intersection loses data rows

Tags: intersection, tabulate

I am running the tabulate intersection tool for two vector shapefiles - lines and polygons.

I am using it to calculate the length of various road classifications (i.e. arterial, collector, highways, local roads) within a given set of census block groups. Using the GEOID of each block group as zone fields and the functional road classification of US roads as the class fields, I should have somewhere between 1-4 records for each GEOID in the output. However, I lose roughly 4,000 of ~26,000 GEOID records in the output.

I looked back at some of the GEOIDs missing tabulate intersection output and they definitely have the class features (AKA roadways) that I am trying to calculate for them, so I'm unsure as to why the tool skipped them?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. All questions here should always include the GIS software in use, including the version number/release name, and include details on the exact command being used. Please [Edit] your Question to contain sufficient details to generate an answer.